# div row and columns background color

Tags: html, css, backbone.js, row

Im having problem with my row's background i cant maximize the content to the left  so i have this little space with different color.

screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/tO0Sm.png

I need to change that small remaining space with the same color as the content.

CSS

```
.row .twelve {
    background: #f2eee3;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="row" style="box-shadow: 0 3px 0px 0px #888888,  7px 0 7px -4px #888888, -7px 0 7px -4px #888888;">
<?php get_header(); ?>
            <div id="content">              
                <div class="twelve columns clearfix">
                    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clearfix'); ?> role="article" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">

                        <section class="nine columns clearfix" itemprop="articleBody" style="border-right: 1px solid #a79c7f; min-height:450px; background:transparent;">
                        <!-- article header -->
                        <header>
                        <!--h1 class="page-title" itemprop="headline"><?php the_title(); ?></h1-->
                        </header> 
                                    <!-- end article header -->
                            <?php the_content(); ?>

                        </section> <!-- end article section -->
                        <?php get_sidebar(); // sidebar 1 ?>
                        <footer>

                            <?php the_tags('<p class="tags"><span class="tags-title">Tags:</span> ', ', ', '</p>'); ?>
                        </footer> <!-- end article footer -->
                    </article> <!-- end article -->             
                    <?php endwhile; ?>      
                    <?php else : ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>    
                </div> <!-- end #main -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
        </div> <!-- end #content-->
```

i changed the html to this and apply some inline styles but my problem now is that the border from the content doesnt align to the header and footer cuts.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzT1J.png

LINK FOR THE WEB-

http://fabioide.com/frederiksminde/vaerelser/

Comment: the screenshot url redirects to a null page

Comment: sorry. I replaced the link now.

Comment: from this we cant check the css but i think there is padding on main article please check it if it is there

Comment: removing the padding makes the border of the content and the footer misalign.

Comment: then instead of removing it from article shift it inside the child div it will do the trick

Comment: wait a minute there is no such space when i am checking here... i double checked in chrome and firefox

Comment: give me the exact thing because i think im doing the wrong one not the one you are telling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
.row .twelve {
background: #f2eee3;
padding: 0px; /* added this */
    }

.row .nine {
background: #e8e6d2; /* added this */
}
```

resizing the image of the slider to align it to the dividers below

Answer (score 0):

Increase the width and decrease margin-left value of div. By doing this the gap will be replaced by the div itself.

Comment: thats a bit complicated since im using foundation framework. i cant just increase width

Comment: what is the coverage of outer most div? Means, both content div and  outer div shares the same area except for the gap?